# Invariant $C^\ast$ subalgebras of $C(\mathbb R)$

Tags: c-star-algebras, topological-groups

On the bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, $C(\mathbb R)$,  define the $\mathbb R$-group action of translations $\alpha: \mathbb R \times C(\mathbb R) \to C(\mathbb R)$ as $\alpha_x(f)(y) := \alpha(x, f)(y) = f(y - x)$. Further, let us consider $\beta: C(\mathbb R) \to C(\mathbb R), ~\beta(f)(y) = f(-y)$.

Of course, there are plenty of $\alpha$- and/or $\beta$-invariant $C^\ast$ subalgebras of $C(\mathbb R)$. It is not difficult to come up with subalgebras which are $\alpha$- but not $\beta$-invariant, such as $\{ f \in C(\mathbb R): ~f(x) \to 0, ~x \to \infty\}$. Somehow, all examples of $\alpha$- but not $\beta$-invariant $C^\ast$ subalgebras of $C(\mathbb R)$ I can imagine are of the following kind:

1. They are ideals in some $\alpha$- and $\beta$-invariant subalgebra $B\subseteq C(\mathbb R)$;
2. They are of the form $A = A_0 \oplus \mathbb{C} 1$, where $A_0$ is an ideal in some $\alpha$- and $\beta$-invariant subalgebra $B \subseteq C(\mathbb R)$.

To possibly clarify this: In the above example we have

1. $\{ f \in C(\mathbb R): f(x) \to 0, x \to \infty\}$ is $\alpha$- but not $\beta$-invariant and it is of the first kind; it is an ideal of $C(\mathbb R)$,
2. The algebra $\{ f \in C(\mathbb R): f(x) \to c, x \to \infty$ for some $c \in \mathbb C\}$ is of the form $A_0 \oplus \mathbb C1$ with $A_0$ the ideal of $C(\mathbb R)$ from 1.

So my question is:

Are there examples of $\alpha$- but not $\beta$-invariant $C^\ast$ subalgebras of $C(\mathbb R)$ which do not arise in one of the two ways? Or conversely:

If $A \subseteq C(\mathbb R)$ is an $\alpha$-invariant $C^\ast$ subalgebra (say, without unit), is there always some $\alpha$- and $\beta$-invariant subalgebra $B \subseteq C(\mathbb R)$ such that $A$ is an ideal of $B$?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are looking for. If $A\subseteq C_b(\Bbb R)$ is some algebra without a unit then $A$ is an ideal in $A\oplus\Bbb C\cdot 1$. Similarly if $A$ is a algebra with the unit of $C_b(\Bbb R)$ there exists some maximal ideal $\tilde A$ in $A$, this ideal is also essential in $A$ so $A$ is a unitisation of the ideal $\tilde A\subseteq A$.

Comment: If you start with an $\alpha$-invariant subalgebra $A$, say, without unit, and pass to the unitization $\tilde{A}$, then $A$ is of course $\beta$-invariant if and only if $\tilde{A}$ is. This is exactly how to pass in between the two kinds of $\alpha$- but not $\beta$-invariant algebras I can imagine. I've extended my question to hopefully clarify it. I am not so much asking about the unitization, but rather the interplay of the two group actions on $C(\mathbb R)$ (and subalgebras invariant with respect to them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

Consider the closure of graph $\Gamma$ of
$$\sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|-1}\right), \qquad x\in(-1,1)$$

This is a compact space which looks sort of like this:

[image: sin(1/(|x|-1))]

Basically there are two intervals and that are connected via some line. Chose some homoemorphism of the line in the middle with $\Bbb R$ to embed the algebra $C(\overline\Gamma)$ into $C_b(\Bbb R)$. Now the points on the intervals are explicit examples of "points at infinity" (basically $\overline\Gamma$ is a special compactification of $\Bbb R$ that we have chosen). The $\alpha$-action leaves the points at infinity unchanged and shifts the points on the connecting line forwards and backwards in a way depending on our homeomorphism (but we don't care about the details).

We can choose the identification of the line with $\Bbb R$ in such a way that $\beta$ becomes the map
$$\beta(f)= [(x,y)\mapsto f(-x,y)].$$
Now look at a sub-algebra $A$ of $C(\overline\Gamma)$ defined by:

$$A=\{f\in C(\overline\Gamma) \mid f(1,1) = f(1,-1),  \quad f(-1,-1) = 0\}$$

In other words we want the point at the top right to evaluate to the same thing as the point of the bottom right and the point at the bottom left should evaluate to $0$. This condition is $\alpha$-invariant but not $\beta$-invariant.

Let $g$ be some function on $\overline\Gamma$ with $g(1,1)=1=g(1,-1)$, and $g(-1,1)=1$, $g(-1,-1)=0$. Then
$$(\beta(g)\cdot g) (1,1) = 1\cdot 1, \quad (\beta(g)\cdot g)(1,-1) = 0\cdot 1$$
and clearly $\beta(g)\cdot g\notin A$. But $g\in A$, hence $A$ is not an ideal of any $\beta$-invariant sub-algebra of $C_b(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: How do you show that points at infinity are unchanged?  Or even that the translation action extends to this compactification?

Comment: @Ruy your doubts are justified, the proof depends on the homeomorphism chosen and the statement is not actually true for every homeomorphism. In the following I describe a homeomorphism for which it is true. Take as a map $\Bbb R\to [-1,1]$ something that for large enough $x$ is equal to $1-\frac1{\sqrt x}$. Now suppose $\xi_n\to 1$ so that $\sin(\frac1{|\xi_n|-1})\to y$ for some $y$, let $x_n$ be the pre-image of $\xi_n$. We want to show that if you plug $1-\frac1{\sqrt{x_n-T}}$ into the $\sin$ you still get $y$ (here $T$ is an arbitrary but fixed translation). [...]

Comment: [...]so:$$\sin\left(\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt{x_n-T}}-1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt{x_n}}-1}\right)=-\sin(\sqrt{x_n-T})+\sin(\sqrt{x_n})$$we want this to go to $0$, multiply by $T/T$ and apply the mean value theorem to get:$$=-\frac1{2\sqrt{\mu_n}}\cos(\sqrt{\mu_n})$$with $\mu_n\in[x_n-T, x_n]$, ie $\mu_n\to\infty$, hence the expression _does_ go to zero. All this explains that there _are_ homeomorphisms $\varphi$ for which you get from $(\xi_n, \sin(...))\to (x,y)$ that $(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(\xi_n)-T)), \sin(...))\to(x,y)$. [...]

Comment: [...] This implies that for functions for which the limits $f(\varphi^{-1}(\xi_n))$ exist you also have that the limit $f(\varphi^{-1}(\xi_n)-T)$ exists, ie that the sub-algebra is actually invariant under translations. Further it also shows that the limits agree, ie the points of infinity are not moved around by the translation.

Comment: Nice!  I think this is now OK.